# Azure Container Registry - price per Gb or Cached Images TTL

Tags: azure, azure-container-instances, azure-container-registry

i am new on Azure.
I will use Container Registry, but Azure has different pricing model. Different as GCP and AWS.
Pay per day for 10 Gb. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/container-registry/

But i have only one image for 500Mb. 5$ per Month is not a big money, but i would like to pay for my 500Mb but not for 10Gb which i don't use.

**Is there a workaround?**

If I pull the image from other repo. Will be image bei Azure cached? If yes, then what is TTL for my image? I cannot find the info.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-faq#how-can-i-speed-up-the-deployment-of-my-container

Thanks for advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no workaround to reduce the payment. For example, the Basic SKU include at least 10 GB storage, you can't pay less than $0.167 each day for the storage, even if you only use 500MB. Just like you use a part of something, but you can't only buy the part, you need to buy the whole thing.

> If I pull the image from other repo. Will be image bei Azure cached?
> If yes, then what is TTL for my image?

The cache images mean Azure already pulled the images and don't need to pull again. The time to pull your custom image depends on two things. One is if the base image or your custom image in the list of the cached images. Another one is that how many layers your custom image have except the cached image. So Azure suggest you switch to use the cached image as the image or the base image and try to create less layers.